# How to use tikz to draw the following paint growth model schematic diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How to use tikz to draw the following paint growth model schematic diagram[image]

Comment: A good start: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Comment: Can you help me to draw picture, l’m novice in tiki. It’s hard for me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I offer two different approaches (Ti*k*Z and PGFPlots). It's difficult to know which is the best one because we don't know if you want to draw the graph "by hand" (as I did), or you have a function, or a data file,... If you have a function or a data file I'd go for the second option made with PGFPlots.

Well, in either case isn't hard to modify one of the following pictures and adapt it to your needs.

```
\documentclass[multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% options for the second picture
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{tick style={draw=none}}

\begin{document}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,scale=1.5]
\draw[-latex]   (-4,0) -- (4,0) node [above] {$r$};
\draw[-latex]   (0,0) node [below] {$O$} -- (0,4) node [right] {$q(r)$};
\draw[dashed]   (-1,0) -- (-1,3);
\draw[dashed]   (1,0) node[below] {$R_0$} -- (1,3);
\draw[dashed]   (2,0) node[below] {$(R+R_0)/2$} -- (2,1.2);
\node[below] at (3,0) {$R$};
\node[red]   at (3,3) {Ti{\itshape k}Z};
\draw[blue,thick] plot[rounded corners=0.5cm] coordinates {(-3,0) (-2,0.8) (-1.25,3) (1.25,3) (2,1.2) (3,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [%
      width=12cm,
      xmin=-4,
      xmax= 4,
      xtick={0,1,2,3},
      xticklabels={$O$,$R_0$,$(R+R_0)/2$,$R$},
      hide obscured x ticks=false,
      ymin= 0,
      ymax= 4,
      yticklabels={},
      axis lines=middle,
      domain=-3:3,
      smooth,
      xlabel={$r$}, 
      ylabel={$q(r)$}, 
      axis equal image=true,
   ]
   \addplot[blue,thick] coordinates {(-3,0) (-2,0.8) (-1.25,3) (1.25,3) (2,1.2) (3,0)};
   \addplot[dashed]     coordinates {(-1,0) (-1,3)};
   \addplot[dashed]     coordinates {(1,0)  (1,3)};
   \addplot[dashed]     coordinates {(2,0)  (2,1.2)};
   \node   [red]        at (3,3) {PGFPlots};
 \end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]